# Override variable in ajax success function, alert outside - Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let's say I have this variable named **nom** that has a value of **lol**.

```
var nom = "lol";
```

Then I have this ajax function, if the data is false, I want to override the value of **nom** to **whay**, assuming the data is **false**.

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "micro/wave.php",
    data: { username: "some string" },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == false) {
            nom = "whay";
        }
    }
});
```

Then if I alert the variable **nom**, it still alerts **lol**, it should alert **whay** because the data is false.

```
alert(nom);
```

Any solution for this stuff?

Comment: where is the alert.. I assume it is not inside the success handler

Comment: see [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify `dataType`, it is most probably a string. Because `("false" == false)` is false

Do this:

```
success: function(data) {
        if (data == "false") {
            nom = "whay";
        }
    }
```

Also, `alert` should be in success handler. Because A in Ajax means **Asynchronous**

Comment: mostly because the alert is not inside the success handler and so the alert might get executed before the ajax request is completed

Comment: yeah, but my answer is reasonable too

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is an asynchronous request, if you put the alert outside the success event, it wont wait for the success event to happen. So it will alert the previous value. So try like this

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "micro/wave.php",
data: { username: "some string" },
success: function(data) {
    if (data == false) {
        nom = "whay";

    }
  alert(nom);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that could be going wrong...

You are declaring variable somewhere where it' not created properly.

You are forgetting that ajax is async by default so alert function runs before success function... you can change that though.

You success function only runs if request is successful not when there is anything wrong...if you are expecting it to fail then that function won't execute use .done instead.